# How to run android application compiled from NetBEANS 7?

Tags: android, netbeans

Ive been able to compile an android application in netbeans and run it by installing the app (copy and paste in the device then install) but this is not a convenient process.. I would like to be able to compile then it start on my device directly (since the emulator is really slow) It is possible ? From what i am seeing in netbeans when you compile it open a dialog so we can choose a virtual machine or a running device .. However my device isnt shown in the running device part..

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing to check is to run this command:

adb devices

from the command line (BTW, are you using Windows, Linux or what?). It shows the connected devices (and emulators). If you see your device listed, then we have a bug of the NetBeans plugin (I assume you're using it). Otherwise, you have a problem in the device configuration.

Comment: Thanks i figured out. also i was needing some USB driver to make it work.